# MySQL:- Fetch records between two specific months and years

Tags: mysql

I need a Query to fetch records between two specific months and years also, Presently I am fetching only current year records like this

```
SELECT material_status, COUNT(*) c
FROM purchase_order
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND material_status='Closed';
```

But I want the records between Current year "April Month" to Upcoming year April Month" means `2016-April to 2017-April` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE date_created >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
  AND date_created  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

This will work 'correctly' regardless of whether `date_created` is `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or even something with microseconds.

But it does not include any part of April for next year?  Is that 'correct'?

Actually it does not make sense -- If "date_created" is always some time in the *past*, why reach into the *future*?

For April of last year through March of this year:

```
WHERE date_created >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND date_created  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
```

Comment: Hey @Rick James the above query is working fine but i want to fetch record in between `2015-april to 2016 april` means interval 2 years then how ?

Comment: I added an example -- is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but for previous year like 2015-April to 2016-April.

Comment: Yes I got it So many thanks , Again great job :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    SELECT material_status, COUNT(*) c
    FROM purchase_order
    WHERE date_created 
         between str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
            AND DATE_ADD(str_to_date(concat(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
     AND material_status='Closed'
     GROUP BY 1;
```

But: `BETWEEN` is inclusive.  If `date_created` is really a `DATE`, then this includes 4/1/2017, but not the rest of 4/2017. Use `last_day()` function on `to date`, i.e.

```
last_day( str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score -1):

#### SQL:

`WHERE date_field >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND date_field < '2018-04-01 00:00:00'`

#### To make it generic, we need to conditionally change Year based on current month

```
WHERE date_field >= (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)>= 4 THEN concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) ELSE concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1, 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) END
) 
AND date_field < (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)>= 4 THEN concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+ 1, 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) ELSE concat(
            YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 
            '-04-01 00:00:00'
        ) END
)
```